# How to use number values from database into variables

Tags: php, database, variables, math

Hello how I could take values from database and put them into variable so i could use them in math operators, because right now when i try to do it showing blank. when i write
`echo $row['sugeneruoja'];`
it shows the value but when i try to do math like
`$Investment = $Investment+1+$MonInvestment*12))*1+$row["sugeneruoja"]*$Interest);`
it's not working

Comment: Showing the code would help.

Comment: <?php
while(true) {
    
    
    if($Investment >= $TotalInvestmentDesire) break;

    if($Year == 0){
        echo "<table border='1' cellspacing='0' >";
        echo "<td>Metai</td> <td>Sukaupta suma:</td>\n";
        $Year= 0;
      }
    $Year++;
    $Investment = ($Investment+(1+$MonInvestment*12))*(1+$row['sugeneruoja']*$Interest);
    echo "<table border='1' cellspacing='0' >";
    echo "<td>" . $Year  . "</td> <td>" .  " &nbsp € " . round($Investment,5) . "</td>\n";
}
}
?>

Comment: Did you verify all your  variables actually have values? Is your sql correct?

Comment: Yes i did and checked a lot of times, is it posible to put $row['sugeneruoja'] into variable ?

Comment: $row['sugeneruoja'] is a variable. It's an array item. It's a valid variable. You have have a problem some where in your code. With out being able to see the life cycle of the variables. It's going to be guessing. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?.